# How to center rows in multiline set

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I've created a multi-line set like this:

```
\begin{align*}
\Set{ \begin{array}{l}
(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),(1, 7),(1, 8),(1, 9),(1, 10),\\
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5),(2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 20),\\
\vdots\\
(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5),(10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10)
\end{array}}
\end{align*}
```

I'm getting this right now:

[image]

Ideally, I would want each individual line to be horizontally centred, as well as the `\vdots`.

Apologies if this isn't the correct way to go about the task at hand; I'm a LaTeX rookie.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `\begin{array}{c}` (`c` instead of `l`).

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank you, that worked brilliantly! Is there some sort of "docs" pages for these commands to learn about their options and so on?

Comment: I think this post could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner I learned LaTeX starting from http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could employ a single `Bmatrix` environment in an unnumbered displayed equation:

[image]

Compared with the `\left\{ \begin{array}{c} ... \end{array} \right\}` approach, the `Bmatrix` solution typesets its contents a bit more compactly.

Type `texdoc amsmath` at a command prompt to open the user guide of the `amsmath` package in a pdf viewer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'Bmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),(1, 7),(1, 8),(1, 9),(1, 10),\\
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5),(2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 20),\\
\vdots\\
(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5),(10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10)
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```